# what's the difference between view's hidden = yes and alpha = 0.0f

Tags: ios, uiview, hidden, alpha

I have a question about `UIView`, what's the difference between views hidden, alpha and opaque?

The effect of setting view: hidden = yes and view.alpha = 0.0f is the same.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The differences are subtle.
According to the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html):

- `opaque` tells the system that the view has no transparency and is thus faster to render because calculations for blending can be skipped
- `hidden` is boolean property that changes only the visibility of the current view and hides it from ui events.
- `alpha` is an animatable property

Setting `alpha = 0.0f` or `hidden = YES` has the same visual effect.
However using `hidden` to actually hide a view not only in a graphical sense but also from ui events might result in a more efficient responder chain when you have lots of nested views.

Comment: +1 Note that UIKit does actually treat very-low alpha elements as hidden for the purposes of UI events. The last time I experimented with it, the threshold was 0.1, but this isn't documented and the specific threshold shouldn't be relied on. But if you animate alpha to 0, it isn't generally necessary to then hide it too.

Comment: In case you're wondering like me, if they are somehow connected, the answer is no. If you set the `hidden` property to `YES`, then changing the `alpha` won't have any visual effect.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case that the actual `hidden` property is set to `YES` when the alpha of a property gets set to 0.0f - you can check with the debugger for yourself

Comment: As an addendum, hiding a view in a UIStackView's arranged subviews does not have the same effect as setting the alpha as 0

Comment: I believe that the view with alpha = 0 will still receive gesture events, such as tap or drag.

Answer (score -3):

`setting view.hidden = yes` will hide the view and `view.alpha = 0.0f` will set the colors of view alpha 0.0 which will make the view invisible, so both are not same.... :)

Comment: by setting view.alpha = 0.0f, iOS also sets view.hidden = yes internally, in fact, there is a threshold for alpha (0.1f), for alpha values smaller than this threshold, view.hidden gets set to YES.